# jQuery not working in .net update panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using the following jquery tooltip script on a page with an series of hyperlinks within an update panel:

```
this.tooltip = function(){      
    xOffset = 50;
    yOffset = 20;       

$("#tools a").hover(function(e){                                              
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";                                      
    $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;        
    $("#tooltip").remove();
}); 
$("#tools a").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});         
};


$(document).ready(function(){tooltip();});
```

It works fine on initial load but not when an ajax call has been made. I believe I should be using .on instead of .ready but I'm unsure how to apply as the following is not working:

```
$(document).on(function(){tooltip();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to fix this. IMO the easiest solution for this problem is to use **Sys.Application** inside UpdatePanel to call JavaScript, jQuery functions after each Asynchronous post back event.

Refer link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534587/ASP-NET-jQuery-is-not-Working-in-UpdatePanels

Comment: Thank Monika, Sys.Application.add_load(tooltip); did the trick!